# How do I search and remove a node from this linked list without using the Linked List class?

Tags: java, loops, search, linked-list, nodes

I am currently practicing data structures and I am trying to remove a node passed as an argument to a method. The method is supposed to search the list for the arg'd song, return the index of the node, and remove it from the list. I am a bit stuck and can't quite figure out how to remove the node without having the previous nodes data. I'm not sure if this can be salvaged or if my approach is completely wrong.

```java
public int remove(Song song) {
        int index = 0;
        Song temp = first;
        while (!temp.equals(temp.next)) {
            if (temp.equals(song)) {
                temp.next = song.next;
                return index;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

This is the class for the nodes I am using.

```java
public class Song {
    String title;
    String artist;
    Song next;
    public static final Song END = new Song();

    public Song(String title, String artist){
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
        next = END;
    }

    // This is used to construct the END Table.
    private Song() {
        title = "";
        artist = "";
        next = this;
    }

    public boolean equals(Song other) {
        if (this.title.equals(other.title) 
         && this.artist.equals(other.artist))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Relevant parts of the playlist class

```java
public class Playlist {
    String name;
    Song first;
    public Playlist(){
        name = "library";
        first = Song.END;
    }

    public Playlist(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        first = Song.END;
    }
```

Currently my code only removes the node after the one I am trying to remove. I am not sure how to go about pointing the node before the node to be removed at the node after it. Any help is appreciated as I am quite stuck here!

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you, but I think it's weird that a `LinkedList` class would allow someone outside the class to access its own internal implementation details and expect the leaked node to be removed by anyone other than the `LinkedList` itself. Unless someone is trying, or expecting, to write very "clever" code, you need to start at the root of the list. All in all, the `LinkedList` implementation is unlikely to be a good one if it's leaking its internal nodes like that.

Comment: @code_dredd I'm not sure I'm advanced enough to understand your comment, but in case it clears it up the method I am writing is part of a linked list class (playlist). The playlist class has a head and name variable and the constructor initializes the head = Song.end. There is another class that has a menu with controls to pass along arguments to the playlist methods. Let me know if this clears it up at all or more clarification is needed.

Comment: Based on your accepted answer, I seem to have misunderstood what you meant due to your phrasing; you seem to be assuming that your function is being given a pointer to the node at the *root* of the linked list, in which case, yes, you need another `prev` pointer variable to trail the `current` node pointer by one node, so that you can re-link `prev` to `current->next` before deleting `current`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also keep track of the previous node while iterating through the list. When you find the node that needs to be removed, update the `next` pointer of the previous node to skip the node to be removed.

So something like:

```java
public int remove(Song song) {
    int index = 0;
    Song temp = first;
    Song prev = null;

    // check if the first node is the one to be removed
    if (temp != null && temp.equals(song)) {
        first = temp.next;
        return index;
    }

    // iterate through the list and search for the node to be removed
    while (temp != null && !temp.equals(temp.next)) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp.next;

        if (temp.equals(song)) {
            prev.next = temp.next;
            return index + 1;
        }
        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see! I knew there should have been a second variable keeping track but I wasn't sure how to implement it. Tysm!